# Cannot resolve error encountered when creating auto layout constraint for view to have a specific height

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, autolayout

When trying to have a bar with subviews at a specific height, I encounter this error and have not been able to resolve it yet.

Unable to parse constraint format: 
Options mask required views to be aligned on a vertical edge, which is not allowed for layout that is also vertical. 
V:|[mainView][barView(==50)]|

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory -- if your views are stacked on top of each other, you can't also align their vertical edge. You probably mean to align their left or right edges (NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft or NSLayoutFormatAlignAllRight).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are stacking views vertically you will need to choose a horizontal alignment such as NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft so that the layout system knows how to arrange them.